# Chrome showing SSL crossed out on my SSL page?

Tags: ssl, google-chrome

Go to https://liquor.com/cask-bulleit/, then click BUY to get into the SSL enabled pages in Chrome.

Why is it that ONLY in Chrome I see the https crossed out (http://screencast.com/t/xcamgjats1kJ) when I am on the SSL required pages? Seems weird that I don't get any errors in Firefox or Safari, yet in Chrome I do. The SSL is valid and works (http://screencast.com/t/0gOdu3aQTk) so I am lost on what the issue is.

After some thought I am thinking that I must have direct links to non-https URLs on the checkout pages, and only Chrome is telling me about this but not other sites? If this is the case, then what happens if I really need those direct non-https links on the checkout/SSL pages??

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some non-HTTPS connections in your HTTP requests. For one example on your site, http://liquor.com/wp-content/plugins/visitorcontact/css/visitor-contact.css?ver=abc, is HTTP . You have a ton of HTTP requests happening, with some failures.

Why can't you request these files in HTTPS? Using relative paths to your assets will usually take care of this.

UPDATE: FireBug
[image]

Comment: yeah i thought as much. how are you able to see that, by just viewing the source and going through each line?

Comment: No :). I use Firebug extension in Firefox, but there are a lot of tools. Fiddler and Chrome Developer Tools has the Resources tab to view all requests.

Comment: under Firebug, what exactly are you using?

Comment: I added an image to my answer.

Comment: awesome u really helped me out

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Nice looking site by the way.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are accessing/referencing unsecured(http://....) resources change those to https instead you will be fine. We had the same issue where we were referencing JQuery plugin from google we changed it to https and it worked.